# How to chose options in a while loop

Tags: while-loop, python-3.6

My program --> I Will ask the user to introduce a number and I want to make that if the number is not in a random sequence (I choose 1,2,3) of numbers, the user need to write again a number until the number they enter is in the sequence:

```
a = (1,2,3)
option = int(input(''))
while option != a:
    print('Enter a number between 1 and 3 !!')
    option = int(input(''))
```

So as you can see I use the variable as a tuple but I don't know how to do it.. =(

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the use of a tuple is obligatory, you will need to get input as a `string`, because it is iterable type. It will alow you easily convert to `int`, sign by sign, thru list comprehension. Now you have a list of `int`s, which you simply convert to a `tuple`. The final `option` variable looks:

```
option = tuple([int(sign) for sign in str(input(''))])
```

But consider keeping your signature in `int` instead of `tuple`. `Int` number is also unequivocal if its about sequence. In python `123 == 132` returns `False`. That way, you need only to replace:

```
a = (1,2,3)
```

by a:

```
a = 123
```

And script will works.